# Adding custom metadata to Azure virtual machine

Tags: powershell, azure

I have several test Virtual Machines running in Azure, to save costs I would like to turn them off outside work hours.

I know this is easy to accomplish with a Powershell script.

However, sometimes I will turn on a long running process and would like to avoid the VM to be shutdown automatically for (for example) one night.

I could of course create a local database on the machine with the script that keeps this information and update that whenever it's required, but I would prefer a solution where I can store a Boolean (or string, or integer, or DateTime) value as a property of the VM in Azure so that it can be detected by the script while it's enumerating the VMs.

Is it possible to store custom metadata with an Azure VM, and read it back from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to store custom metadata with an Azure VM, and read it
>   back from a script?

It is certainly possible to do so. Each resource in Azure can define up to 15 unique key/value pairs as `tags` and you can query for resources on tags as well. Tags are typically used for organizing the resources (e.g. cost center etc.) but they can be used for setting any custom property on a resource as well.

For more information about resource tags, please see this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/resource-group-using-tags/.

Comment: Tags seem to be specific to resource groups rather than individual VMs. I can make this work by having a tag that contains the names of individual VMs in the resource group to not shut down.

If nobody comes up with an answer for individual VMs within 24 hours, I'll accept this as the answer (since it's definitely useful information :))

Comment: Actually, it looks like you can tag a VM as well, but I don't see it in my portal: 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-tag/

I'll look into it further ...

Comment: Even though the link I mentioned talk about tags at a resource group level but you can definitely set tags at individual VM (or for that matter any resource in your Azure Subscription) level as well. I would encourage you to try this out on Azure Portal for your VM.

Comment: Found it, I am using "classic" VMs, which do not support the interface. I can work with this answer by using the resourcegroup to store a list of names (that is shorter than the max length). Once we move to the RM VMs, it will be easy to port the code to save data on VM level. 

Thanks! :)